# RMI problems with Java 7_25 and 7_40 Applets: Connection Reset

Tags: java, applet, rmi

I’m trying to make my code work for Java 7 Update 25 and Update 40 for Applets.

All worked fine on earlier Versions of Java, but since Update 25 the RMI causes problems only in Applets - I guess this has something to do with the new security features of java.

There are multiple things that look weird to me, and I don’t really know where to start.

- Symptom 1:

When I’m trying to debug, everything works, until somewhat of a timeout (about 20 seconds) then the RMI just closes the Connection and throws the Error Message: `"Connection Reset"`

- Symptom 2:

When am looking at the Java Console, is throwing a “`java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect`”, but I’m not able to debug that. I set the remote debugger to listen and used following startup properties:

`-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=8000,suspend=y`

It seems like that Exception occurs before the debugger has the connection.

- Symptom 3:

In the Java Console again it gives me the Warning:
`basic: WARNING - specified JRE version, null is invalid platform version.`

Google said nothing to that, and I have no clue where this comes from.

I’ve investigated all three symptoms but haven’t got any way to make it work.

Has anyone of you a hint for me what’s exactly may be different in the newer Versions and in Applets that causes such problems?

Comment: Well seems it can't connect to the server. Did you looked if it's sending connection requests or if its blocked by Java new security?

Comment: `SocketExceptions` and `IOExceptions` don't have anything to do with Java security, and not much to do with Java itself. 'Connection reset' and 'Network unreachable' are network conditions, not Java conditions, and not subject to change across Java versions.